# Clicking on label of Liferay AUI checkbox changes value of the preceding checkbox

Tags: checkbox, liferay-aui, liferay-6.2

I wrote this simple form in Liferay:

[image]

```
<aui:input type="checkbox" name="team" value="joe" label="joe" checked="false" />
<aui:input type="checkbox" name="team" value="ben" label="ben" checked="false" />
```

**PROBLEM:** When I click on the label "**ben**", the value of the **joe** checkbox changes.

Is my syntax incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

By default aui assign the name as `id`. So it is not unique and `onclick` triggers the wrong input id (which is the first input).

Just set a unique id to each input should works.

```
<aui:input id="chkbox1" type="checkbox" name="team" value="joe" label="joe" /> 
<aui:input id="chkbox2" type="checkbox" name="team" value="ben" label="ben" />
```

Answer (score 0):

No. `name` has to be unique for checkboxes, just like normal HTML.

```
<aui:input type="checkbox" name="teamAAA" value="joe" label="joe" checked="false" />
<aui:input type="checkbox" name="teamBBB" value="ben" label="ben" checked="false" />
```

Did you mean to use `type` radio? Those would need the same `name`.

```
<aui:input type="radio" name="team" value="joe" label="joe" checked="false" />
<aui:input type="radio" name="team" value="ben" label="ben" checked="false" />
```

**Update**:

`<aui:input>` will normalize `name` and `id` if `id` isn't explicitly passed. So in your code, but inputs have the same `id`, which causes the wrong input to be focused when clicking the label.

Comment: Pretty much any HTML tutorial that I could find uses the same `name` for several boxes: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlcheckboxes.php

Comment: Never use W3Schools as an authoritative reverence. See: http://www.w3fools.com/. Check [MDN <input>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-type) instead. "Radio buttons that have the same value for the name attribute are in the same "radio button group""

Comment: See also: [WHATWG Writing a form's user interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#writing-a-form's-user-interface)

Comment: So it looks like I was a bit wrong. You can use the same `name` for checkboxes but the `value` sent to the server will be comma separated. I updated my answer to reflect how `<aui:input>` behaves.